# If both lateral limits are equal to +∞, then does that limit exist?

Tags: limits, functions

If you have a function $f$, for example, when $x\to a$, and its lateral limits are both equal to $+\infty$, does that mean that the limit of $f$ when $x\to a$ does not exist?

Edit: By lateral I mean: x→a− and x→a+

Comment: By lateral you mean the limits as $x\to a-$ and $x\to a+$?

Comment: It means $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)=\infty$.

Comment: Limit exists, but infinite. Finite limit not exist. (lateral I understand as in AlvinL's
  comment).

Answer (score 2):

It depends.

For a (say) complex-valued function $f\colon X \to \mathbb{C}$ considered over the space $\mathbb{C}$, no, the limit does not exist; *i.e.* it fails to converge. Instead, we say that the limit *diverges* to $+\infty$.

This is because $+\infty$ is not an element of the set $\mathbb{C}$.

If you are instead considering a function in the context of a space with infinity, *e.g.* the extended real line $\mathbb{R} \cup \{-\infty, +\infty\}$, then yes, the limit exists and is $\lim_{x \to a}{f(x)} = +\infty$.

Beware, however, that $\lim_{x \to a}{f(x)} = +\infty$ is also often used as a notational convention to say that the limit diverges to (positive) infinity.

In general, consider whether $+\infty$ is an element of the space you are considering to determine whether the limit exists. (If you aren't yet considering spaces, you're working in $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, where such a limit *fails* to converge.)